# ExtJs 5.0.1 "Layout run failed" using column-layout

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I upgraded a Sencha ExtJs project from version **4.1.1** to the new released version **5.0.1** and now get
the error **"[E] Layout run failed"** in the webdev console.
In the older version everything works as expected.

The error message comes from the **column** layout, used in a container nested in the two filsets.
When I exchange the layout to e.g. vbox then no error occurs.

What is wrong in the following code which lets the layout run fail and how to fix it.
Thank's for every hints, tips or solutions.

The fiddle can be found at https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/8ov

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

  Ext.create('Ext.form.FieldSet', {
      title: 'Grouping Fieldset',
      layout: 'anchor',
      renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
      items: [
          {
              xtype: 'fieldset',
              title: 'Fieldset - 1',
              layout: 'anchor',
              width: '100%',
              items: [
                  {
                      xtype: 'textfield'   
                  },
                  /*...more input fields...*/
                  {
                      xtype: 'container',
                      layout: 'column',
                      width: '100%',
                      items: [
                          {
                              xtype: 'textfield',
                              width: 25
                          },
                          {
                              xtype: 'textfield',
                              width: 50
                          },
                          {
                              xtype: 'textfield'
                          }
                      ]
                  }
              ]
          },
          {
              xtype: 'fieldset',
              title: 'Fieldset - 2',
              layout: 'anchor',
              items: [
                  {
                      xtype: 'textfield'
                  }
                  /*...more input fields...*/
              ]  
          }
       ]
    });
});
```

The stack trace using Ext.Loader:

```
log Util.js:704
logx Util.js:744
Ext.apply.log.log.error Util.js:748
Ext.define.handleFailure Context.js:597
Ext.define.runComplete Context.js:1129
callOverrideParent Ext.js:58
Ext.Base.Base.addMembers.callParent Base.js:1256
Ext.override.runComplete Component.js:174
Ext.define.run Context.js:1120
Ext.define.statics.flushLayouts Component.js:182
Ext.define.statics.resumeLayouts Component.js:198
Ext.resumeLayouts Component.js:5948
Ext.define.render Renderable.js:685
Ext.define.constructor Component.js:1743
constructor Class.js:29
(anonymous function) VM1725:3
Ext.ClassManager.Ext.apply.create ClassManager.js:1413
Ext.define.launch Application.js:10
Ext.define.onBeforeLaunch Application.js:407
Ext.define.constructor Application.js:325
constructor Class.js:29
(anonymous function) Application.js:23
Ext.env.Ready.invoke Ready.js:271
Ext.env.Ready.invokeAll Ready.js:313
Ext.env.Ready.unblock Ready.js:445
Ext.apply.triggerReady Loader.js:761
Ext.apply.checkReady Loader.js:906
Ext.apply.load Loader.js:592
Ext.apply.require Loader.js:477
Ext.apply.triggerReady Loader.js:733
Ext.apply.checkReady Loader.js:906
Ext.apply.onLoadSuccess Loader.js:649
Ext.Boot.Request.notify bootstrap.js:904
Ext.Boot.Request.processLoadedEntries bootstrap.js:883
Ext.Boot.Request.loadEntries bootstrap.js:856
Ext.Boot.Boot.processRequest bootstrap.js:451
Ext.Boot.Boot.load bootstrap.js:472
Ext.Boot.Boot.requestComplete bootstrap.js:507
Ext.Boot.Request.notify bootstrap.js:908
Ext.Boot.Request.processLoadedEntries bootstrap.js:883
Ext.Boot.Entry.notifyRequests bootstrap.js:1328
me.fetch.complete bootstrap.js:1242
readyStateChange
```

---

**Update**

When I put **every textfield** in an **own container** the layout error is gone and the gui is 
acting like expected.
But this is only a workaround...

The fiddle can be found at https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/8re

```
//...items of secound fieldset
{
  xtype: 'container',
  layout: 'column',
  items: [
    {
      xtype: 'container',
      items: [
        {
          xtype: 'textfield',
          width: 50
        }
      ]
    },
    {
       xtype: 'container',
       items: [
       // ...nesting next textfield in container
```

Comment: Two remarks : 1. you talk about column layout, but your code has anchor layout. 2. The stacktrace with ext-all-debug is not very useful. Use Ext.Loader instead. The page load is much slower, but the errors are much more meaningful.

Comment: Yes in the fieldset I use the anchor layout. But the deepest container in the fieldset uses the column layout, which causes the layout run to fail.

Answer (score 3):

Layout run failures often happen when you have an inner container (e.g., your "column" layout) with a stretched width INSIDE a parent container (e.g. your "anchor" layout) with a stretched width.

In short, the framework can't appropriately size things because it's all stretched. It could be your anchor layout, the column layout, or one of the other stretched things in there. This is commonly known as "over-nesting".

The top-level container in your code appears to be a fieldset - inside of which you have another fieldset (etc), and both have anchor layouts. More than likely you want to be using "hbox" or "vbox" layouts.

Comment: OK but when I use hbox/vbox layouts instead the fieldsets take not all of the space. The float of the columns layout is not working anymore. When the width is reduced the textfields should float to the next line.

Comment: How can you find out which component is failing the layout?

Comment: There's a tool that ships with the SDK download called "page-analyzer" (under /examples/) that can help. Also, the Google Chrome extension "App Inspector for Sencha" has a similar tool.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem with the column layout. After some hours of search I discovered that I should define the [columnWidth](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-cfg-columnWidth) for each component that is placed in the container that has the column layout.
It worked for me.
I have just rechecked the docs for [column layout](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Column) where they say:

> ColumnLayout does not have any direct config options (other than inherited ones), but it does support a specific config property of columnWidth that can be included in the config of any panel added to it. The layout will use the columnWidth (if present) or width of each panel during layout to determine how to size each panel. If width or columnWidth is not specified for a given panel, its width will default to the panel's width (or auto).

For me it works only with columnWidth config. (I am using buttons instead of panels in the column container)